# WPF: How to draw this polygon?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to draw the following red polygon:
[image]

The problem is if I use somethign like this:

```
Polygon poly = new Polygon();
poly.StrokeThickness = 2;
poly.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
PointCollection points = new PointCollection();

for (int i = 0; i < this.NumberOfMetrics; i++)
{
   points.Add(new Point(MAX_VALUE - this.Metrics[n, i] * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(i * (360 / (this.NumberOfMetrics)))), MAX_Y_GUI - this.Metrics[n, i] * Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(i * (360 / (this.NumberOfMetrics))))));
}       
poly.Points = points;
```

Then the polygon is always "filled" and in the example above the red and green polygon is drawn.

I already tried to add the 4 "inner" points to the PointCollection, but then nothing is drawn. So how can I achieve that?

I tried the solution proposed by David:

```
for (int n = 0; n < this.NumberOfRevisions; n++)
            {
                Path path = new Path();

                CombinedGeometry geometry = new CombinedGeometry();
                geometry.GeometryCombineMode = GeometryCombineMode.Union;

                Polygon poly = new Polygon();
                PointCollection points = new PointCollection();

                for (int i = 0; i < this.NumberOfMetrics; i++)
                {
                    points.Add(new Point(MAX_VALUE - this.Metrics[n, i] * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(i * (360 / (this.NumberOfMetrics)))), MAX_Y_GUI - this.Metrics[n, i] * Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(i * (360 / (this.NumberOfMetrics))))));
                }

                poly.Points = points;

                geometry.Geometry1 = poly.RenderedGeometry;


                geometry.Geometry2 = poly.RenderedGeometry;


                path.Data = geometry;

                polygons.Add(poly);

                paths.Add(path);
            }
```

This is just a test but I thougth so I should get the same result as before, but it isn't drawn anything. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the red polygon first, then drawing the green polygon?  Also, where are you changing the color so that one is red and the other is green?

Comment: I think a little context as to what this data is might help.

Comment: @dthorpe yes I did this and then it works since the second polygon is on top of the first. But i one of the colors is transparent, it isnt working anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have 2 independent shapes, with the possibility of the green one to be transparent as you stated in your comment, the best way to do is to use a combined geometry:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms653071%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

with the help of this, you can first create the green geometry, then the red by subtracting the green (or a copy of it) from the red one to create the hole.

So basically:

1. red shape, PLAIN
2. green shape on top of it, PLAIN
3. Subtract green shape or copy of it from red shape >> hole in red shape

this way you get the effect you want

easier done in Xaml, a bit more complicated in C# but still doable.

**Edit:** set the Combined Geometry as a Path's Data:

```
Path myPath = new Path();
CombinedGeometry myCombinedGeometry = new CombinedGeometry()

// here you set the combinedGeometry's geometries to create the shape you want

myPath.Data = myCombinedGeometry;

myGrid.Children.Add(myPath);
```

by the way, the PATH will be the place where you set the Fill / Stroke attribute for the colors, not the inside geometries. (see the examples in xaml in the link above, you basically just have to translate the code into C#)

**Edit2:**

don't forget to set a Fill on the Path:

```
for (int n = 0; n < this.NumberOfRevisions; n++)
{
    CombinedGeometry geometry = new CombinedGeometry() { GeometryCombineMode = GeometryCombineMode.Union };

    PointCollection points = new PointCollection();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.NumberOfMetrics; i++)
    {
        points.Add(new Point(MAX_VALUE - this.Metrics[n, i] * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(i * (360 / (this.NumberOfMetrics)))), MAX_Y_GUI - this.Metrics[n, i] * Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(i * (360 / (this.NumberOfMetrics))))));
    }

    Polygon poly = new Polygon();
    poly.Points = points;

    geometry.Geometry1 = poly.RenderedGeometry;
    geometry.Geometry2 = poly.RenderedGeometry;

    polygons.Add(poly);

    paths.Add(path = new Path() { Data = geometry, Fill = Brushes.Red, Stroke = Brushes.Transparent });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I already thought about thissolution, but I have one issue...How can I add this Geometry object to my UIElement (for example a grid) because Grid.Children.Add(Geometry) isn't allowed.

Comment: you have to create a Path object and set the geometry as the path's data, see my Edit

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but somehow I still have troubles. Therefore I edited my question.

Comment: you did not set any Fill for the polygon, see my edited answer